# How Secure credit card Increase Cibil Score?

Tags: credit-card, india, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I have Low Cibil Score(628). Take Example, I buy secure credit card say for Rs.25000, and i get Credit Limit as Rs.20,000.I do use Secure credit card 50% every month.And i pay EMIs correctly.  Than how it will increase to improve my Cibil score over the period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And i pay EMIs correctly.

Are you saying you will make payments in Full? Or are you saying you would make purchases that qualify for EMI over a period of time?

> how it will increase to improve my Cibil score over the period?

The Score will start showing improvements within few months and keep increasing over the period of time provided you pay the full outstanding every month.

**Edit:**
You have to pay all your loans on time to see a better score. If you open another line of credit and pay it regularly and at the same time not pay your other loan, it may not increase the score to that extent.

Comment: I have 1 loan. I have to pay 4000 as EMI. But for some reasons i didnt pay it for last 5 months.So my cibil score reduced.  So my question is instead of paying that 4000 EMI, If i buy Secure credit card and use it  properly will increase cibil score?